# Who moderates the moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

On Jan 8th I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652409/how-does-jquerys-load-interpret-the-url-parameter). It was quickly closed by a moderator (and so later automatically deleted) after a handful of views. The moderator attempted to answer the question, incorrectly, in a comment, which I replied to. On Jan 9th I asked an almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663126/history-pushstate-url-interaction-with-jquery-load-causing-page-fetch-failure), which I think I answered in the 'Edit 2' section. The answer is unrelated to the original moderator's comment.

A couple of days later I flagged the original post for moderator input, asking why it had been deleted. I've heard nothing since.

Irrespective of the technical merit, or otherwise, of the original question, this appears to me to be unacceptable behaviour. A moderator arbitrarily closed the question with no close votes and a handful of views, and no-one has responded to my request for feedback. So what exactly is this 'moderator' thing? Do you just get carte blanche to do whatever you want, or are you at least meant to interact with the community at some level?

Comment: Your original question wasn't deleted by a moderator, rather it was [roombaed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) (see the last section re the "*If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...*")

Comment: Had you edited the question to make it clearer, addressing the issues in the comments it might have been reopened. As you didn't, the system assumed you'd abandoned the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson: the mod didn't say the question was unclear; he said it had "nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery", before giving an *incorrect* answer, *in a comment*, **and** closing the question. Given this, surely my only option was to ask the question again, rather than attempting to persuade him to re-open it?

Comment: The fact that no one else commented, and that the mod closed it 2 days after their comment, after you had added no further details in the question (by means of an edit) speaks for itself there. Yes, you should have edited it to improve it. Then, like the others said, it wasn't the mod that deleted it. It was automatically deleted, by [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), as the question appeared to have been abandoned.

Comment: @Larnu: why do you say that the mod "closed it 2 days after their comment"? If the times on SO are to be believed, I posted the new question 16 hours and 14 minutes after the first question, *after* the first question had been closed. I didn't have to edit the question: the mod didn't ask for clarification. I instead replied to his comment.

Comment: Please note that flags are not the way in which moderators "interact" with the community. They are unsuitable for a dialog, and we aren't even given enough space to explain why we took a particular action in response to a flag. As a matter of policy, we decline "please reopen this question" flags as not things that require moderator attention, since the community can vote to reopen without moderator intervention. You can encourage a community review of a closed question by editing it, addressing the confusion/misunderstanding that led to its being closed.

Answer (score 10):

The thing to do here would have been to edit your question.

If you think someone (moderator or not) misunderstood what you wrote then edit the question so that nobody else can be confused. Equally if there's an incorrect comment, edit the question to explain why your question is not about that or why the comment does not help you. This applies whether or not your question is currently closed.

If the question is closed, editing it would put it into a review queue for reopening so at that point you just need to find 3 reviewers who agree that the question should be reopened, and that's what would have happened. There are a lot more users with close/reopen privileges than moderators. You have the rep to cast a reopen vote yourself so in your case you only need 2 others to agree with you.

Even if your question still doesn't get reopened you might get some more useful comments from those who do see it in the reopen queue.

I note that the "nearly identical question" still doesn't have any actual answers so simply reasking it has not turned out to be a panacea for you.

If you make a complaint against the moderator who closed the question, I imagine the result would be to ask you why you didn't try any of the above first.

Answer (score 9):

Disregarding the specific example you bring forward: to deal with perceived moderator abuse you have these specific avenues to make your case:

- Use the contact form and to raise the issue to SE employees.
- Raise a custom moderator flag to make another moderator aware of your perceived problem.
- Bring up the issue in meta, raise a stink publicly, and hope for the best. Be aware that by choosing this path your actions will also come under scrutiny and the crowd may not necessarily be sympathetic.

We have a **much** reduced community manager team; and many/some moderators are not participating at full capacity (plus the raft of recent resignations, caused by the company’s extremely poor handling of several issues).

So asking in meta could be the best choice at the moment. Although as mentioned earlier without a very solid case that may backfire.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I only raised the issue here as a last resort because I was unaware of either of your first two options, despite a lot of searching on the FAQ and the moderator tag. Have I missed something obvious? Any more clues, please? :)

Comment: To clarify... the contact form seems bit OTT. I'm sure the employees have more important things to worry about. What is a 'custom moderator flag'? All I can see is a flag for 'in need of moderator intervention', which is what I originally tried.

Comment: @EML Your flag read *”I'd like to make a complaint about the arbitrary way in which this post was closed. How do I do that? Note that the comment left by the closer was both incorrect and unhelpful.”*. That’s not really actionable by a moderator. Flags are no way to start a back and forth conversation. If you’d have written why exactly the moderators action was wrong and what you’d like to have done about it, something might have happened.

Comment: @EML A custom flag is what you used. But without a solid case, your flag will be declined. In your case, the flag you used included **no** case. Just a claim of "the mod actions were wrong". For a flag like this to be actionable, it needs to provide an explanation of why you disagree with the moderator's actions. If there was a case of a very obvious mistake (fat fingers pushing the wrong button), another mod may want to take action. But this was not the case here, so a more solid justification would be required.